# Heroku. db:push when I app contains two databases

Tags: heroku

I have Rails 3.2 application hosted on Heroku. My application contains two databases (one for my model, the second is a kind of a dictionary with static data).

I need to push the second database (dictionary) to Heroku, but when I try db:push Heroku thinks that I'm going to push the first database (with Rails model).

The question is - how could I specify that I want to push my local database dictionary.sqlite to heroku dictionary.pg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Heroku pg:transfer plugin which will let you set the target destination by it's URL.

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer

Alternatively, use psql client locally but restore to the heroku pg isntance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `db:push/pull`; those methods are deprecated. Use `pgbackups:capture/restore` for things like this. It accepts the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR` as part of the command:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR 'https://example.com/data.dump' --app app-name
```

See [Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) for more detailed explanation.

Also, `heroku-pg-transfer` has been integrated into `pg-extras`, check that out here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras